# SQLIte return last value that contains, but i want THe exact

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to use this sqlite to query the "1" only idlei value, but if I have

> idlei = 1
>
> idlei = 180

and search for "1"

it will return me the 180, but I want the 1 only.

```
   c = sdb.query("marcacao", new String[]{"idlei", "paragrafo", "marcacao"},
            "idlei" + " LIKE ?",
            new String[]{"%" + idlei + "%"},
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only return the 1, you need to use "=" instead of "like"

```
c = sdb.query("marcacao", new String[]{"idlei", "paragrafo", "marcacao"},
        "idlei" + " = ?",
        new String[]{idlei},
```

Comment: To flesh this out-  LIKE %?% will find any string with that value in it anywhere (the % is a wildcard and will match anything).  LIKE generally isn't used with numeric values, but with strings.